# Magento 2.2 Store Selector not showing on the front end?

Tags: magento2.2, theme, multistore, xml, default.xml

I've literally put this in my theme's `default.xml` file:

```
<block class="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="store_switcher" as="store_switcher" template="Magento_Store::switch/stores.phtml"/>
```

And the store switcher is not showing up. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you created store view in backend ?

Answer (score 1):

Please mention the reference container where do you want to add the store switcher. See the below code for reference:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="footer">
            <block class="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="store_switcher" as="store_switcher" after="footer_links" template="Magento_Store::switch/stores.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

You need to mention 2 things one is reference container where you want to show the block and second one is the after="footer_links"(Not necessary but needed if you want to order the switcher position through xml).

Hope this helps.